# SSL (Hosted on LB) to be installed on the Downstream Apache Servers?

Tags: apache-httpd, openssl, ssl, load-balancing

First, I have very basic knowledge on the SSL topic.

Here is my setup. I have (1) of Public Facing Domain on LB and (2) of Internal Domains on each Web Servers. Like:

```
             [https://public.com][LB]
                         |
          -------------------------------
          |                             |
https://web1.internal.com    https://web2.internal.com
```

So that, yes, there also are INTERNAL ENCRYPTIONS just between LB & Two Nodes (Apaches). (REQUIRED)

I am taking care of the Two Nodes (Apache Servers) but not the LB part. And was able to setup 2 Internal SSLs on these Apaches.

Then my Security Team says (who is taking care of LB Part) I will have to:

- install the SSL Cert (of `public.com`) inside each of my Two Apaches, along with the Internal Domain SSLs.
- And they passed me the `public.com.crt` *(Naming for example)*

What actually does it mean please, since I don't even need to have the `Virtual Host` for that Public Domain above. It doesn't even reach to my Apaches.

- How (where) do I setup the SSL of the LB inside my Internal Nodes (Apaches) please?